# Sharepoint 2010: ADO.NET/WCF Data Services (listdata.svc) exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: sharepoint-2010, odata, wcf-data-services

I am trying to get some list information from a Sharepoint 2010 using the ADO.NET/WCF Data Services = listdata.svc.

It works fine when I am trying this with the browser - as long as I am already logged into the Sharepoint site.

But when I try to access the same URL programmatically (using a test console application), it does not work. Using Fiddler, I see that I get a 302 error that says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

### Here is my test code:

```
Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("Starting...") 
    Dim dc As New MyDataContext(
    New Uri("http://myurl/mysite/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/"))
    dc.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("[[MyUserName]]",
                                           "[[Password]]")
    Dim results = From x In dc.Tasks
                  Select x
    For Each item In results
        Console.WriteLine(item.Title)
    Next 
    Console.WriteLine("Finished. Press any key to exit the application.")
    Console.ReadKey()
 End Sub
```

Does anybody have a good idea on how to fix this problem?

Looking forward to get a solution ;-)

Marcel

Answer (score 0):

start by looking in both the event logs & sharepoint logs in the 14-hive.  the 302 HTTP status code is 'found', not error, i suspect your problem is related to security.  in the code you posted there is no domain specified.

Comment: The problem is that my Sharepoint site sits on a shared server, therefore I do not have access to the logs. But I agree with you that it must have something with security to do.